# OGR2OGR - converting a GML file to GeoJSON

Tags: ogr2ogr, gml

I'm struggling to use ogr2ogr to convert a GML file into a GeoJSON file. My input is zipped GML files with several layers. I'm only interested in the layer with name 'TopographicArea'.

I've tried converting using the following at the command line:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON .\3925845-HW5929.geo.json .\3925845-HW5929.gz
```

This fails with the error:

```
ERROR 1: Layer 'TopographicPoint' does not already exist in the output dataset, and cannot be created by the output driver.
```

I'm presuming this is because GeoJSON doesn't support layers.

How can I tell ogr2ogr to ignore all layers except one?

P.S. I have thousands of GML files to process, so this needs to be scriptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the 'layer' option:

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON .\3925845-HW5929.geo.json .\3925845-HW5929.gz LayerNameHere
```

Alternatively, if you need more control, you could use a SQL query with the '-sql' option.

Comment: The syntax is actually `ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON .\3925845-HW5929.geo.json .\3925845-HW5929.gz LayerNameHere`. You can check what layers exist in the .gz file with `ogrinfo .\3925845-HW5929.gz`.

Comment: Specifying multiple layers fails. From the help output it looks like the layers should simply be separated by space. Exporting the layers one-by-one works.